# Dropbox Update - Go To File Explorer When Clicking On The Folder Icon On Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dropbox

My Windows 10 Dropbox app just updated and I noticed that when I click on the directory icon after I open up the Dropbox app, it no longer takes me directly to the Dropbox folder using File Explorer.

[image]

How do I restore the previous behavior where clicking on the icon will take me to Windows File Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it in Dropbox's "Preferences" screen:

[image: (Screenshot of the 'General' tab)]